# How to render text in an edit form that uses CKEditor

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, laravel-8

I have created a custom blog form that uses CKEeditor for submission. By default it inserts `<p>` tag that my laravel model stores in the db without any issues.

I can view it in my blade files using `{!! $variable !!}` without any issues. However, when I edit the post the old text doesn't show up in the CKEditor. Without CKEditor I can see the text. E.g. `<p>` tag shows along with the text. But CkEditor is all blank.

Example Blade Form Code -

```
<textarea class="ckeditor form-control" name="basics" id="basics" cols="30" rows="10" value="{!! old('basics', $basics) !!}" placeholder="{!! old('basics', $basics) !!}"></textarea>
```

2nd Attempt:

```
<textarea class="ckeditor form-control" name="basics" id="basics" cols="30" rows="10" value="{!! $basics !!}" placeholder="{!! $basics !!}"></textarea>
```

The Last Attempt:

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="basics" id="basics" cols="30" rows="10" value="{!!html_entity_decode($basics!!}" placeholder="{!!html_entity_decode($basics)!!}"></textarea>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if textarea has a value property. Try `<textarea class="form-control" name="basics" id="basics" cols="30" rows="10">{!! $basics!!}</textarea>`

Comment: just put the raw value `<textarea class="form-control" name="basics" id="basics" cols="30" rows="10">{{ $basics }}</textarea>` and yes as @porloscerrosΨ mentioned, textarea does not have a value attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked:

`<textarea class="form-control" name="basics" id="basics" cols="30" rows="10" value="basics">{!! $basics!!}</textarea>`